# Portal Verification codes getting undeliverable

Tags: customer-portal, self-registration, experience

For my portal users, I created a self registration portal.  The users get sent a verification code after they register but certain domains are not working and I cannot figure out why.  gmail and company emails are sending the admin an 'undeliverable' email message but .edu emails are working fine.

Where can I look to allow pretty much all emails?

Comment: One possibility: you didn't set up [SPF/DKIM/DMARC](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000389240&type=1), thus it gets treated as spam by GMail.

Comment: @identigral no, the admin gets an 'undeliverable' email sent to them.  It doesn't reach the gmail or company spam.

Comment: Take a look at the [logs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.emailadmin_monitor_emails_sent_from_salesforce.htm&language=en_US&type=5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be an issue with the default 'Experience' page set up for the Site.  I changed it to the 'Default' Salesforce login and my issues went away.